# Azure Release Pipeline - Dedup size does not match the downloaded size. DedupId:

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a release pipeline which contains different stages for different sections of the website. However one of the stages throws an error when downloading the artifact. The other stages work as expected.

**Error:**

> ##[error]One or more errors occurred. (Dedup size does not match the downloaded size.

I cannot find anything only that explains to me what Dedup is with regards to Azure Pipelines

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems relevant with the recently [event](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) on Azure Devops. In addition, this issue is more for agent.

If this issue occurred on what you are using is Hosted agent, just change to using your private agent to finish the release pipeline. Besides, if you are using private agent, please ensure the version of agent you are using is the latest one: [2.155.1](https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.155.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.155.1.zip).